# Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component declared with prefix t but no taglibrary exists for that namespace

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, custom-component

I am using `JSF 2.2` and I would like to create a `custom component` using annotations. However, when accessing *welcome.xhtml* I get a following error:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component declared with prefix t but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

Maybe the problem lies in the fact, that I cannot use "createTag" in `@FacesComponent` annotation

```
@FacesComponent(value="components.HelloWorldComponent")
public class HelloWorldComponent extends UIComponentBase{

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "hello.world.component";
    }

    @Override
    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        writer.write("Hello everyone");
    }

}
```

and here is my `welcome.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
     xmlns:t="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/component"
   >
    <h:head>
        <title>Hello World - Input Form1</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name}"
                p:placeholder="What's your name?" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="hello" />
        </h:form>
         <t:helloWorldComponent/>
          <h:outputText value="TEST"></h:outputText>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is where I found out how to do this... Where do I need to register component? https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/11/jsf-2-2-create-a-custom-hello-world-component-in-30-seconds.html

Comment: Please put back `createTag=true` as instructed and tell about the exact error you got.

Comment: I cannot user createTag in my annotation, it says "Change to value"

Comment: Oh? So you got a compilation error? And the *"Change to value"* message is actually being your IDE trying to be helpful? Please reconfirm if the exact error you got is actually *"The attribute createTag is undefined for the annotation type FacesComponent"*. This actually means that you're not using the correct version of the class. The `createTag` attribute was added to the `FacesComponent` type in JSF 2.2. It was absent in older versions.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I got. However, when I check what is the version of my _JavaServerFacet_ in ProjectFacet, it is set to 2.2. So what is exactly the problem here?

Comment: The physical JSF library being loaded by the runtime is actually not 2.2.